# Flink Tumbling Window labelling

Tags: apache-flink, data-stream

I have a scenario with a flink application that receives data streams in the following format:

> { "event_id": "c1s2s34", "event_create_timestamp": "2019-03-07 11:11:23", "amount": "104.67" }

I am using the following tumbling window to find the sum, count, and average amounts for input streams in the last 60 seconds.

> keyValue.timeWindow(Time.seconds(60))

However how can I label the aggregated outcome such that I can say that the output data stream between 16:20 and 16:21 the aggregated results are sum x, count y, and average z.

Any help is appropriated.

Comment: How do you want to consume the results -- are you going to print them, or write them to a file, or send them to Kafka, ... ?

Comment: Hi David, I want to send the result to Kinesis Firehose.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the windowing example in the Flink training site -- https://training.ververica.com/exercises/hourlyTips.html -- you'll see an example of how to use a ProcessWindowFunction to create output events from windows that include the timing information, etc. The basic idea is that the process() method on a ProcessWindowFunction is passed a Context which in turn contains the Window object, from which you can determine the start and ending times for the window, e.g, `context.window().getEnd()`.

You can then arrange for your ProcessWindowFunction to return Tuples or POJOs that contain all of the information you want to include in your reports.